# Extension of copulas

Tags: pr.probability, st.statistics

Let $(X,Y)$ be a random vector. Suppose that the marginal distribution functions of $X$ and $Y$ are known (say $F_1$ and $F_2$). Then the joint law of $(X,Y)$ is given by the following formula:

$$F_{X,Y}(x,y)=C(F_1(x),F_2(y)),$$

where C is some copula function. It means, that if the distributions of $X$ and $Y$ are given, we can construct (at least one) joint distribution of $(X,Y)$ conforming with given distributions (e.g. one can set $F_{X,Y}(x,y)=F_1(x)F_2(y)$.

I wonder whether is it possible to extent this property to the case when the distribution of $X+Y$ is known as well (say $F_3$).

My question is: if the distributions of $X$, $Y$ and $X+Y$ are given how can I construct (at least one) joint distribution of $(X,Y)$, conforming with univariate distributions?

Is there any closed-form solution like we have in case when only the marginals are given?

Thank you for the answers!

Comment: I must be missing something in the question. Why not just take $h$ to be anything, and take $D(a,b,c)=C(a,b)$ where $C$ is the function as given before?

Comment: James, thank you for the comment. You can not take $D(a,b,c)=C(a,b)$, because then the law of $X+Y$ would be differ from the given  disribution of $X+Y$, (which is $F_3$). I would like to construct the joint distribution of $(X,Y)$, such that univariate distributions of $X$, $Y$ and $X+Y$ are equal to some given distributions $F_1$, $F_2$  and $F_3$ correspondingly. Do you see my point?

Comment:  To rephrase James comment, the choice $D(a,b,c)=ab$ answers your question. This answer may not interest you as it leads to a trivial construction (independence) but then you should reformulate your question! In addition what does a function need to be a copula (definition?)?  Anyway, maybe you are rising an interesting idea somewhere but I guess you have to think again about your question. Maybe you want to know the whole class of joint distribution $F_{XY}$ that can be written like in your last equation? also maybe you should work with density or characteristic functions? 

Comment: Robin, thanks for the comment. However, if we choose $D(a,b,c)=ab$, then the law of $X+Y$ might be differ from given distribution $F_3$, so we can not do it. We would like to construct such distribution of (X,Y) that the law of $X$ is equal to a given law $F_1$, law of $Y$ is equal to a given law $F_2$ and law of $X+Y$ is equal to a given law $F_3$.

Comment: I just wanted to note that this is equivalent to the previous question http://mathoverflow.net/questions/12853/devise-a-joint-distribution-of-alpha-and-beta

Comment: Gjergji, thanks for the link. However I would like to note that nobody the question in your link question is still open, nobody answered it.

Answer (score 3):

You can not prescribe the distribution of the sum. 
Counterexample: Let X and Y be uniform on [0,1]. Now choose the distribution for X+Y so that P(X+Y < 0.5) = 1. This means P(X > 0.5) = 0 a contradiction to uniform.

A way to visualize this might be looking at mass distributions on the square [0,1]x[0,1]. Prescribing the margins (here uniform) is a restriction on the projections to the axes (i.e. 0x[0,1] and [0,1]x0) and the remaining freedom is distributing the mass in the square.

Comment: I agree with you, that in general case the solution of the problem might not exist. However, the question is how can we find at least one solution if it exists?

Answer (score 0):

OK then another answer to another problem:

An easy and practical way might be discretizing all functions. Then your conditions are linear constraints which can be solved for $C$.

Since one can always transform with the inverse cdf we can assume without loss of generality that both marginal distributions are uniform [0,1]. Let $F$ be the distribution of the sum of the marginals.

Now partition the interval [0,1] into n intervals [k-1/n, k/n]. By taking products you arrive at a partition of the square $[0,1]x [0,1]$ into $n^2$ squares.

Let $C_{i,j}$ be the mass of $C$ on each of the squares of the grid. You arrive at 3 different types of constraints for $C_{i,j}$:

(1) $\sum_{i,j} C_{i,j} = 1$ this is the condition that the copula is a probability distribution

(2) $\sum_{i} C_{i,j} = 1/n$,  $\sum_{j} C_{i,j} = 1/n$ this is the condition that the marginals are uniform

(3) With $I_d = \{(i,j)| i+j = d\}$ the d-th diagonal with d = 2,...,2n the condition on the distribution of the sum is $\sum_{I_d} C_{i,j} = \sum_{I_d} F(1/i + 1/j)$.

These are 1 + n + n + (2n - 1) linear equations for the $n^2$ unknowns.

I guess this will give a numeric solution, a continous solution could be derived by a proper limit argument.

This should work not only for sums but also other functions of X and Y as well.

I hope this helps

Comment: G g, thanks for this idea. However, you missed one more type of constraints. Namely, since $C_{ij}$ is the mass, then $C_{ij}\geq0$  for all $i$ and $j$. So we have $4n$ equations, $n^2$ inequalities and $n^2$ unknowns. How would you recommend to deal with all this numerically?

Comment: Well, you are right of course and nothing is perfect. I noted that I was a bit sloppy with (3) as well (F is a distribution not the mass).

Dealing with this numerically? Well on the one hand this is simply linear optimization. I would get something like Matlab and just solve the equations. On the other hand, the best approach might depend on your specific requirements. If you have a concrete F in mind, say from measurements, this is would be more a problem of statistics than numerics.


Comment: G g, there are two problems if dealing numeric: 1. We have to solve the linear equations and all the inequalities $C_{ij}\geq0$. 2. We have to choose the only one solution among all. We probably can use Lagrange multipliers to deal with this two problems, but I was looking for any kind of closed-form solution (like we have in case where just two marginals are given: $F_{XY}(x,y)=C(F_1(x),F_2(y))$.

Comment: The real question is, given that X and Y are (marginally) U[0,1], which distributions for X+Y are "realizable". For example, X+Y must be supported on [0,2] and have expectation 1.

Comment: Yuval, the answer to your question is given in this paper: "Best-possible bounds for the distribution of a sum — a problem of Kolmogorov" - Frank, Nelsen and Schweizer, 1987.

However, my question is the opposite. Assume, that the distribution of $X+Y$ is realizable. Is there a way to find (at least one) joint distribution of $(X,Y)$.



Comment: Oleg, they show bounds on the cdf of X+Y, but the bounds are only necessary conditions. For the given example, their bounds are the trivial t-1<=Pr[X+Y<t]<=t. They show that for each t, these bounds (when not trivial) are actually attained by some distributions.

These bounds are satisfied by the distributions U[0,1] and U[1,2], which are not realizable. So their characterization doesn't solve my problem.